# Filter function and filter effects

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

My goal is to be able to change the brightness of individual elements, but it doesn't yet seem to be supported. Not only that, but there seems to be discrepancies in what's *supposedly* supported and not. Yet some of the effects clearly work in my browser?

[MDN filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function)

[MDN filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

[caniuse CSS filter() function](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filter-function)

[caniuse CSS filter effects](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

**Are the links above up-to-date?**

**What exactly are the differences between filter function and filter effects?**

**If they are supported, how widespread is the support right now?**

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? I think you need to provide an example as both CSS and SVG filters are supported per the linked documentation by modern browsers.

Comment: @RobertLongson the issue is whether or not the CSS filter function and filter effects are supported or not, and how widespread the support is if these are supported. im also wondering what the difference between the two are

Comment: filter functions are SVG, filter effects are CSS. Their support is as per the can I use links, except the CSS filter() function is not what you're looking for [this is the can i use for the filter functions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters)

Comment: @RobertLongson mdn states _"The <filter-function> CSS data type"_ which kinda contradicts what youre saying regarding filter functions being SVG.

Comment: Brightness is a broadly supported CSS filter effect - please post the code of what's not working and your browser version and make.

Comment: @MichaelMullany i dont plan on coding anything. it was a hypothetical goal. somebody asked me about this, and i couldnt find a consensus online as to whether or not its actually supported. im not even sure what the difference is between filter, filter effects, and filter function. im simply looking for the answers to the **questions in bold** above